# Isomorphism between Quotients of $S^1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$, let $G_n$ denote the subgroup of $S^1$ consisting of the $n$-th roots of unity. Then show that $S^1/G_m$ and $S^1/G_n$ are isomorphic for m, n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$. I was trying to prove by using the natural projection isomorphism between the two groups, but to no avail. Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is no "natural projection" between those two groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the map $f_m:S^1\to S^1$ defined by $f_m(z)=z^m$. Its kernel is
$G_m$.  What happens if we apply the First Isomorphism Theorem to $f_m$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: show that for all $n\in\mathbb N$ we have an isomorphism $S^1\cong S^1/G_m$.